# How to deserialize a ConcurrentMap with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to deserialize an object that has a `ConcurrentMap` in it but I get an exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap field com.example.Row.doubleValues to java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

My function looks something like this:

```
T deserialise(final InputStream input, final Class<T> type) {
  GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
  Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(input);
  return gson.fromJson(isr, type);
}
```

How do I get it to deserialize the map properly? Do I need to provide a custom deserializer?

Note that I have both regular `Maps` and `ConcurrentMaps` in the same class. I am also the one who serializes the class, so, if I can provide a custom serializer that specifies the type of concurrent maps and then a deserializer that specifies how those should be created as objects that should work.

**Update**: The class that I am deserializing looks like this:

```
public class Row implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; //there's a diff value here

    private final String key;
    private final ConcurrentMap<String, Double> doubleValues = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
    private Map<String, String> writeOnceValues = Maps.newHashMap();
    ...
}
```

Comment: could you show the relevant part of the class you want to deserialize into?

Comment: @Katona added an example

Comment: one obvious solution is to change the type of `doubleValues` from `ConcurrentMap` to `Map`, do you really need that? Otherwise you will need custom deserialization, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127904/gson-fromjson-return-linkedhashmap-instead-of-enummap) question, the problem is similar but not indentical and I think that solution (`InstanceCreator`) might work here.

Answer (score -1):

This is my proposed solution with a `TypeAdapter`. Before showing you the code, I have to say that `final` should not be used for a field if field is present into parsed string, since Gson will try to assign value to that field.

My changed `Row` class, just for purpose of showing solution.

```
public class Row implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; //there's a diff value here

    private final String key = "myKey";
    private ConcurrentMap<String, Double> doubleValues = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
    private Map<String, String> writeOnceValues = Maps.newHashMap();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Row [key=" + key.getClass() + ", doubleValues=" + doubleValues.getClass()
                + ", writeOnceValues=" + writeOnceValues.getClass() + "]";
    }

}
```

and the type adapter where I essentially use standard parsing but return a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

```
public final class ConcurrentHashMapTypeAdapter<K,V> extends TypeAdapter<ConcurrentMap<K,V>> {

  @Override
  public synchronized ConcurrentMap<K,V> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
      in.nextNull();
      return null;
    }
    Type aType = new TypeToken<LinkedTreeMap<K,V>>() {}.getType();
    Gson g = new Gson();
    LinkedTreeMap<K,V> ltm = g.fromJson(in, aType);
    return new ConcurrentHashMap<K,V>(ltm); 
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void write(JsonWriter out, ConcurrentMap<K, V> value) throws IOException {
     Gson g = new Gson();
     out.value(g.toJson(value));
  }
}
```

and a test method where I show you that it works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson simpleGson = new Gson();

    // deserialize row once to get a suitable JSON string
    String s = simpleGson.toJson(new Row());
    System.out.println("JSON string: " + s);

    Row r;
    try{
        r = simpleGson.fromJson(s, Row.class);
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Oh no, assignment is not possible");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
    Type aType = new TypeToken<ConcurrentMap<String,Double>>() {}.getType();
    gb.registerTypeAdapter(aType, new ConcurrentHashMapTypeAdapter<String, Double>());

    Gson gsonWithTypeAdapter = gb.create();

    r = gsonWithTypeAdapter.fromJson(s, Row.class);
    System.out.println("Now it works");
    System.out.println("Row: " +r);
}
```

This is my execution:

```
JSON string: {"key":"myKey","doubleValues":{},"writeOnceValues":{}}
Oh no, assignment is not possible
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap field stackoverflow.questions.q18856793.Row.doubleValues to com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:95)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
    at stackoverflow.questions.q18856793.Q18856793.main(Q18856793.java:23)
Now it works
Row: Row [key=class java.lang.String, doubleValues=class java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap, writeOnceValues=class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap]
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `TypeAdapterFactory FACTORY` in `ConcurrentHashMapTypeAdapter` class, if it isn't used anywhere in the example?

Comment: `TypeAdapter<...>` mechanism in Gson is specifically designed to provide information about types where it is not available due to type-erasure in Java. Generified `TypeAdapter` is just wrong.

Comment: @andrybak it's been 3 years. Give me at least 1 day to check the answer..

Comment: @andrybak: the FACTORY field is useless, I do not remember why I put it there, going to remove. About my solution with TypeAdapter, if you have a more elegant way to resolve OP question without TypeAdapter I would be glad to see your answer and compare to mine :). I'm always eager to learn  :). No passive aggressive intent, here.

Comment: @ giampaolo : I am using my own class as a Key in ConcurrentMap and when I am going to deserialize using gson, I am getting java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap is not Comparable
 at com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap.find(LinkedTreeMap.java:164)
 at com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap.put(LinkedTreeMap.java:94)